# Android app multiple imageviews to be loaded together

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, image-resizing

I have the following layout for an activity that displays 4 870x3700 jpeg images (each around 200KB):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/testlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageph" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the below code in my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_pages);
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_17_18_21);
    imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_22_25_29);
    imageView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_30_31_36);
    imageView4.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsz_37_38);
```

Now on a tablet I'm able to display them with no problems but when I try to run the app on my mobile phone it throws an out of memory exception. I've tried several different resizing methods without any effect, even with a simple method to calculate the aspect ratio and return a height given the screen width.

How can I adjust the size of all the images in a way to avoid loading the original sized image into memory and make it scale down to the display screen's width while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

try following

Calculate first the maximum possible inSampleSize that still yields an image larger than your target.
Second Load the image using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options), passing inSampleSize as an option.
Third Resize to the desired dimensions using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap().

Hope this will help you.

```
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Config.ARGB_8888);
float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth(), originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
float scale = width/originalWidth;
float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;
Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);
return background;
```